# supervisord prints logs only when stopped server

Tags: python, django, supervisord

so this is what I print in python with flushing:

```
import sys
print "getting detailed"
sys.stdout.flush()
```

then i check the logs file and it is empty, so then I stop the server:

```
supervisorctl stop my-project
```

and the logs file is filled with messages from the print above, so the question is how to make it print to the log file without stopping the server?

Comment: how are you viewing the logfile?

Comment: @JacobIRR with a nano editor in linux or any other it doesn't matter

Comment: If you open the logfile using `less -F <filename>` and then run the python script (in another tab), does the logfile show new text inside `less`?

Comment: @JacobIRR no it doesn't show anything

Comment: This sounds related to supervisor and its handling of stdout in a special way. Maybe in the config file. I suggest tagging it for supervisor too